# Microsoft Office 2010 reinstall (Windows XP)

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office

I have windows XP professional and microsoft office professional. I just had to replace my hard drive, and I am now in the process of reinstalling all my software. I'm having trouble reinstalling Office.

I bought Office though a job I no longer have, and I can't re-download it. I backed up everything with the XP backup utility before replacing the drive. I thought I would be able to restore Office, but it's not happening.

I restored C:\program files\microsoft office. That replaced the short cut in the start menu, but the shortcut doesn't point anywhere. Clicking on, say, Microsoft Excel results in an error message which says "Problem with shortcut: This action is only valid for products that are currently installed."

I'm thinking I must need to restore more folders, but which ones? Where do all the Office executables usually live?

Comment: You should not reinstall XP, it reached end of support, use one of the newer version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The XP Backup utility is to backup files, specifically user files, to transfer the data between two PCs (or alternatively the same after a clean format). Being a Microsoft product, several components of Office are registered in the System Registry, including the shortcuts.

If you backed up only the files and restored them in their proper paths, will just not make it work :-) You'll need to re-install MS Office all together.